# visual basic game player wont move

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

For a school project I am making a simple game were zombie's walk straight down and try to attack the players base (it is kinda like space invaders and planets versus zombies). however my player has stopped moving when I press D or A, when I try to play the game. I will post my code. can somebody help make my player move side to side?.

```
Public Class Form2
Dim Player_Health As Integer = 10
Dim Player_Max_Health As Integer = 100
Dim Player_X_Speed_Moving As Integer = 0
Dim Player_Potential_X_Speed As Integer = 10

Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        Player_X_Speed_Moving = -Player_Potential_X_Speed
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        Player_X_Speed_Moving = Player_Potential_X_Speed
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        Player_X_Speed_Moving = 0
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        Player_X_Speed_Moving = 0
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Kevin Welch\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Zom-b\Zom-b\My Project\Res\Spr\Player1.bmp")
    bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.White) ' magenta in bitmap will be transparent
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Call MovePlayer()
End Sub
Private Sub MovePlayer()
    PictureBox1.Left += Player_X_Speed_Moving
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the form's message queue is getting backed up with key down events and your Tick event is having trouble keeping up.  Most window UI systems use a single thread that responds to messages that are pumped to them such as key down/up, mouse movements, and clicks.  If the UI thread is busy, your Tick event will have to wait since it runs on the same thread.  Many games have a game loop that processes window events along with processing game logic and graphics rendering.  I would recommend look into using the XNA Framework since it handles most of that stuff for you.

Comment: Just as a side note, XNA is no longer in development.

Comment: I'm sure there are many tutorials online if you look.  @KevinWelch is correct in that it is no longer in development.  They stopped with version 4.0.  I'm not sure what new framework people are using these days for simple .Net game development.  Microsoft has some tutorials for XNA along with a platform example.  That should get you started.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203894(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx